# How to programmatically get SessionStateBehavior for Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET Web Forms I can use the `EnableSessionState` directive to disable Session state for the page in the .aspx file like so:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" ...[other attribs omitted]... EnableSessionState="False" %>`

I can also alter the session behavior for my context like so:

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);`

**QUESTION: How do you *get* the `SessionStateBehavior`?**

`System.Web.UI.Page` has a property for `EnableViewState` but not for `EnableSessionState` as far as I can tell.

I **can** `try` to use Session, but I was hoping for a conditional test instead of relying on exception handling, such as in this example:

```
bool sessionStateEnabled = false;
try
{
  object value = Session["key"]; // throws exception if Session state disabled
  sessionStateEnabled = true; // set true only if exception was not thrown
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // Session state is disabled; 
}
```

Comment: What if you check If(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session !=null) or perhaps create it as a property to be reusable? Any constraints for you in doing so?